# Sorting a DataGridView by date column using a custom IComparer

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting

I have a data grid view on a form with a date column and I would like to sort the column when a sort button is pressed.

Here is the code for the button click event:

```
Private Sub DateOfBirthSortButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateOfBirthSortButton.Click
    PatientDataGridView.Sort(New DatabaseModule.DateComparer)
End Sub
```

And for the comparer:

```
Public outputFile As String = "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\outputTest.txt"

Public Class DateComparer
    Implements IComparer

    ' Compare the two dates
    Public Function Compare(ByVal rowX As Object, ByVal rowY As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare

        'Get the date value from the collection of cells in the row
        Dim dateX As String = rowX.Cells.Item(2).Value.ToString
        Dim dateY As String = rowX.Cells.Item(2).Value.ToString

        'Convert to a date
        Dim x As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateX, "dd-MM-yyyy", Nothing)
        Dim y As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateX, "dd-MM-yyyy", Nothing)

        'Compare
        Dim cmpDate As Integer = Date.Compare(x, y)

        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFile, True)

        objWriter.WriteLine(dateX & " " & dateY & " " & cmpDate)
        objWriter.Close()

        Return cmpDate

    End Function
End Class
```

I have added code which puts the results from the comparer into a text file so that I could see the results of each comparison.

However, when the button is pressed, the comparer only compares the same row against itself, in a seemingly random order, sometimes multiple times.

Here is the initial order (I've given the people numbers to show which order they should sort into):

[image: Initial ordering]

And the resultant order after the sort button is pressed:

[image: Resultant ordering]

And the comparisons recorded in the text file:

[image: Text file results]

If anyone could explain to me how I can fix my problem I would be very grateful, thanks :)

Comment: How did the data get into the DGV?  It is fully capable of sorting dates all by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you have a copy-paste error:

```
Dim dateX As String = rowX.Cells.Item(2).Value.ToString
'  note that DateY is also getting from RowX
'   should be         rowY
Dim dateY As String = rowX.Cells.Item(2).Value.ToString
```

You should also turn on `Option Strict`, `rowX` and `rowY` are passed as `Object` but you are using them as `DataGridViewRows` without casting them:

```
Public Function Compare(X As Object, Y As Object) ...
    Dim rowX = TryCast(X, DataGridViewRow)
```

If/when you do need a custom sorter, you might want write it to allow the column and sort order in the constructor so it can work with more than just one column and be able to flip from Ascending to Descending and back.  Example:

```
' specify the column to sort, and the order:
dgv1.Sort(New DGVPatientSorter(2, thisOrder))
```

---

Since it will allow you to use a Sorter, the data must not be bound.  Too bad.  But, if you define that column as a `Date` type, it will sort dates just fine:

```
dgv1.Columns(2).ValueType = GetType(DateTime)
```

Then sorting:

```
dgv1.Sort(dgv1.Columns(2), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Comment: You *really* dont need it if you tell the DGV it is a Date column

Comment: So how do I do that? I went through the properties of the Collection of columns and I couldn't find an option.

Comment: Its in the answer - you cant do it in the Column designer for some reason. `dgv1.Columns(2).ValueType = GetType(DateTime)`

Comment: Ah, sorry, hadn't finished reading through your answer fully yet :D Thanks for the help, works fine now :)

Comment: If you set it as DateTime, and still keep the sorter, you can use `DirectCast` instead of parse